# How can I link a name to an id in MVC c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to MVC in addition to C#, so...  please work with me.

I'm developing a simple MVC project -

tables - prospects and contacts

My issue comes when I'm trying to link the prospect ID field in the contacts model to the prospect name from the prospect table.

**Prospect Model -**

```
public class Prospect
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCde { get; set; }
}
```

**Activity Model -**

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int ProspectId { get; set; }
    public int ProspectName{ get; set; }
}
```

**Activity Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Activities.ToList());
    }
```

**Activity Index View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Type, "Edit", "Activity", new { id=item.Id }, null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProspectId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProspectName)
    </td>
    <td>

        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

How can I link the prospectname to the prospectid in the activity model.

Eventually, I'd like to essentially join an activity to a prospect always, so the id and name are both automatically generated, but for now, I'm fine writing in the prospect id.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand completely your requirement.

In Edit when you trying to change the Activity instead if textbo, use the dropdown which showing all the available `Prospect` Ids so one can select from only available Ids. So if you have available Prospect Id you can easily get its Name from table.

Comment: I agree that it should be easily to get the name if I have the id, but I'm not familiar with the syntax to do so.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of the necessary code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need help with the LINQ statement?  If so, it would look something like this...

```
    Prospect p = dbContext.Prospects.Where(p => Name == "Smith").FirstOrDefault();
```

(...replacing "Smith" with whatever the name is, obviously).

Comment: I apologize, I reversed my goal.  I have the ID, and I'm trying to pull the name linked to that ID, but I think I can just swap out for your above.  Is there a way to replace "Smith" with an item place holder, something like:

Comment: Prospect p = dbContext.Prospects.Where(p => p.Id == item.Name").FirstOrDefault();